# How do I perform a filter on the FK I'm aggregating on in a QuerySet?

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have a (working) query that looks like

```
authors = Authors.objects.complicated_queryset()
with_scores = authors.annotate(total_book_score=Sum('books__score'))
```

It finds all authors who are returned by a `complicated_queryset` method, and then sums up the total of the scores of their books. However, I wish to amend this QuerySet such that it only includes the scores from the books published the last year. In pretend syntax:

```
with_scores = authors.annotate(total_book_score=Sum('books__score'),
                               filter=Q(books__published=2015))
```

Is this possible with QuerySets or do I have to write raw SQL (or, I guess, two separate queries) to get that behaviour?

Comment: Yes. What's not working for you? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Brandon From what I can tell, it does not treat the `filter` keyword argument as an actual filter. I get no error message, but also no filtering is performed.

Comment: filters end up as where clauses

Comment: @Brandon Is that behaviour of Aggregates/annotations documented somewhere?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: @Brandon There is no mention of using filter as a keyword argument on that page.

Comment: filters are applied to querysets as a whole, not to individual aggregations or annotations. To the best of my knowledge, you can't selectively apply an annotation or aggregation only for specific rows.

Comment: @Brandon And I'm asking specifically whether it's possible to filter based on the FK relation I'm aggregating on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96697/discussion-between-brandon-and-kqr).

Comment: You can filter on the FK of course, but to the best of my knowledge, you can't do the aggregation for only rows where the FK matches. You would create a new queryset, filtering on the FK, then the aggregation/annotation would be applied to all objects in the queryset.

Comment: @ShangWang That will only show me authors who have books published this year, yes, but it will count the total score of all their books, regardless of when they were published.

Comment: @ShangWang That has pretty much the same effect in this case, I think. Since the "base object" of the query is an Author, any `filter` on the queryset will just exclude authors from the result set, not books from the aggregation.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your schema, sorry for the randomness. It might be more helpful if you post a minimal model code for both `Book` and `Author`. How about doing the query on `Book` with a statement something like `author__in` to refer to the `authors` you've got? Although the performance might suffer if you have a lot of books.

Comment: @ShangWang In the end, I want to access the `total_book_score` for every author, so I can't end with a query on `Book`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) if you're using Django 1.8+

**DISCLAIMER**: The following code is an aproximation, I haven't tested this, so this could not work exactly in this way.

```
# You will need import:
from django.db.models import Sum, IntegerField, Case, When, Value

with_scores = authors.annotate(total_book_score=Sum(
    Case(When(books__published=2015, then=Value(F('books__score'))),
        default=Value(0), output=IntegerField())  # Or float if it fits your needs.
    )
)
```

Comment: This looks pretty cool. Unfortunately I'm stuck on Django 1.4 for the time being. :(

Comment: I decided to do a raw query for the time being, since I'm stuck on 1.4. Once I upgrade to 1.8 (which is hopefully rather soon) I'll keep this solution in mind. Cheers.